# What is SpeedSurfing?

Tags: antivirus, antimalware, terminology

My Sophos antivirus detected what it calls "SpeedSurfing", and my Google-fu is failing me. The Chrome extension it deleted was [Boomerang for Gmail](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/boomerang-for-gmail/mdanidgdpmkimeiiojknlnekblgmpdll).

[image: Sophos Scan Results]

Comment: Heh, searching for "speedsurfing sophos" on Bing returns this question as the only result. I have a feeling this is a term specific to Sophos antivirus.

Comment: Amazing how fast bing was able to index these new questions

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Boomerang extension interacts with the Gmail website making lots of HTTP requests. That behaviour is usually associated with malicious extensions which attempt to exploit advertisement networks by simulating user clicks.

Sophos seems to have invented a neologism and does not seem to explain it even in their own documentation. You may try [opening a support ticket](https://secure2.sophos.com/support/contact-support.aspx).